# LINQ to Entity join query

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have the following setup:

Table `ShoeAreas` that has columns `ShoeId` and `MaterialId`.
Table `Shoes` that has columns `ID` and `Status`.

I have a method that takes one argument - `materialId` and the goal is to determine if there is a record in `ShoeAreas` with a `MaterialId` equal to the one passed like an argument. And if such a record (or records most probably) exist if they are relateed to shoe from `Shoes with`Status` = Production.

I tried this :

```
 return shoeService.All().
                Join(shoeAreaService.All(),
                s => s.ID,
                sa => sa.ShoeId,
                (s, sa) => (sa.MaterialId == matId)).
                Any(s => (s.Status == (byte)EntityStatusProd.Production)));
```

But I get error on the `Any..` line saying `} expected` and also this is my second Linq to Entity query that I write so I have doubts if it's syntax problem or the query is wrong itself.

Comment: With proper Entities you should be able to use Navigation Properties instead of Joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `IEnumerable<bool>` from `Join` method (values of condition `sa.MaterialId == matId`). Create anonymous type which will hold both joined entities instead:

```
 return shoeService.All()
           .Join(shoeAreaService.All(),
                 s => s.ID,
                 sa => sa.ShoeId,
                 (s, sa) => new { s, sa }) // here
           .Any(x => (x.sa.MaterialId == matId) && 
                     (x.s.Status == (byte)EntityStatusProd.Production)));
```

Comment: Thanks, gonna use your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:  (linq )

```
from shoe in Shoes 
join shoeArea in ShoesArea on shoe.ID equals shoeArea.ShoeID
where shoeArea.MeterialID == matID && shoe.Status == (byte)EntityStatusProd.Production
select new {shoe.ID,shoe.Status};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 return shoeService.All().Any(s => shoeAreaService.All()
                                .Any(sa => sa.MaterialId == matId 
                                        && s.Id == sa.ShoeId)
                          && s.Status == (byte)EntityStatusProd.Production);
```